# jQTouch, scroll to bottom of page

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, jqtouch

I'm using the JQTouch framework for building an iPhone app/WebPage. I have it working nicely, but i cannot make it scroll to the bottom of the page.

```
    <body>
        <div class="current">
            <div class="toolbar">
                <a class="back button" href="javascript:{}">back</a>
                <h1>header</h1>
            </div>
    </div> 
        <ul id="myContent">
            <li>Item 1</li>
            <li>Item 1</li>
            <li>Item 1</li>
        </ul>
        <div id="myInput">
          ...a couple of input elements..& submit button
          that results in the "myContent" being updated with another li
        </div>
    </body>
```

Basically I have a UL at the top of my page, that gets updated/added to via server events coming in. This works nicely, but i want to be able to scroll to the "myInput" div which is at the bottom. However, I can't find a way of achieving this, I'm either using libraries incorrectly, or missing a trick. Any ideas?

Cheers

Comment: What JavaScript and jQuery are you using?  It's hard to figure out the script problem without the script :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the size of your webview? I had this issue but it was because I set my webview height to 480 (so it was off the screen due to the navigation bar)